# Git: move last changes from release branch to differs greatly branch branch

Tags: git

In my android project I used github and git last version. 
I have "master" branch which which is ready for release, and "next" branch which have which includes major changes. 
I should implement last ~80 small commits from master branch to next. Them make other developer. But probably some shanges are not needed or could not be implemented in next brach. 
The way I'm going to follow is checkout to "next" branch and make cherry-pick of range of last 80 commits. Like this:

```
git cherry-pick 6f12..73f5
```

Probably cherry-pick will be broken of conflicts, I will resolve it, commit changes, call

```
git cherry-pick --quit
```

and run cherry-pick again from first commit after that what was brokenm like

```
git cherry-pick 34e2..73f5
```

Is that way correct or what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `git cherry-pick --continue` after it halted for conflicts. That will make it automatically continue where it left off.